# How to compare time between midnight and other specified time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if time has passed 12:00 AM midnight.

```
var today = new Date();
var h = today.getHours();
var m = today.getMinutes();
var s = today.getSeconds();
var ms = today.getMilliseconds(); 
time = h+"."+m+"."+s+"."+ms;
```

I want to compare time between 12AM to 6 AM
something like

```
if (time >= 0.0.0.000 && time <= 6.0.0.000)
{mystuff}
```

But this is not working. Any suggestion where is the miss.

Comment: `time` is a string. Compare it with strings.

Comment: I'd also be very worried if `time` were somehow *less than zero*...

Comment: What do you mean by if time were less than zero? please explain.

Comment: Well for `time` to be less than zero, it'd have to somehow mean that `today.getHours()` returned `-1` or less... Now, I've seen badly coded clocks display `24:00:00` at midnight, but never one showing `-1:00:00` at any time...

Comment: `0.0.0.000` is invalid syntax. Did you want to create a string, like `"0.0.0.000"`?

Comment: No, I made that `0.0.0.000` for comparison. I just want to compare current time to see if its between 12AM and 6AM.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing a string is not normally something you would want to do if it contains numbers that you are actually interested in. But if that can't be avoided you could do:

```
if(parseInt(time.split('.')[0]) < 6) {
    console.log('DoStuff');
}
```

Then you split on '.' and take the first part and turn that into a number and check that the hour is before 6.

Or if you had a number already:

```
if(h < 6) {
    console.log('DoStuff');
}
```

Both should work if you want to check for the time being between 12AM to 6 AM.

Answer (score 2):

I would compare time in that way

```js
var currentD = new Date();
var startHappyHourD = new Date();
startHappyHourD.setHours(17,30,0); // 5.30 pm
var endHappyHourD = new Date();
endHappyHourD.setHours(18,30,0); // 6.30 pm

console.log("happy hour?");
(currentD >= startHappyHourD && currentD < endHappyHourD )?
    console.log("yes!"):
    console.log("no, sorry! between 5.30pm and 6.30pm");
```

The `setHours()` method sets the hours for a specified date according to local time, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC until the time represented by the updated Date instance [for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours).

Comment: here `currentD = new Date()`  if I am comparing current time right?

Comment: @Mask, yep, that is for current time